# Why is Apacheds not importing users with the top attribute set in the ldif file?

Tags: ldap, apacheds

Apacheds apacheds-2.0.0.AM26.exe. Importing ldif file with Apache Directory Studio 2.0.0.v20210213-M16

When "objectClass: top" is included in my ldif file I get an invalidAttributeSyntax error. Full error below.

I have deduced that it is the top attribute because all the other attributes show up normally in the log. The top one shows up as **objectClass:: dG9wIA==**.

If I remove top it works. If I put top back and import again with the update option it works.

Error:

```
#!RESULT ERROR
#!CONNECTION ldap://myhost:10389
#!DATE 2021-05-27T11:13:27.212
#!ERROR  [LDAP result code 21 - invalidAttributeSyntax] INVALID_ATTRIBUTE_SYNTAX: failed for MessageType : ADD_REQUEST Message ID : 17     Add Request : Entry     dn: uid=jsmith,ou=Users, dc=example,dc=com     objectClass: top      objectClass: person     objectClass: organizationalPerson     objectClass: inetorgperson     uid: jsmith     givenName: Jerry     sn: Smith     cn: Jerry Smith     userPassword: 0x52 0x61 0x74 0x31 0x6F 0x6E 0x61 0x6C  : ERR_13246_INVALID_VALUE_PER_SYNTAX Invalid upValue per syntax dn: uid=jsmith,ou=Users, dc=example,dc=com changetype: add uid: jsmith givenName: Jerry sn: Smith cn: Jerry Smith objectClass:: dG9wIA== objectClass: person objectClass: organizationalPerson objectClass: inetorgperson userPassword:: UmF0MW9uYWw=
```

Ldif data:

User:

```
dn: uid=jsmith,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
givenName: Jerry
sn: Smith
objectClass: top 
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: inetorgperson
uid: jsmith
cn: Jerry Smith
userPassword: MyPasswordInClearText
```

Ldif to create the Group and Users objects which I have tested both as part of the larger ldif file and as two separate imports. This part first then the users second.

```
dn: ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalunit
objectClass: top
ou: Groups

dn: ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalunit
objectClass: top
ou: Users
```

Comment: is the LDIF file imported correctly if you keep `top` but remove `person` from the list of object classes?

Comment: @scottysseus No, same thing